# GridView doesn't show the real size of the images

Tags: android, gridview

I'm working on an application that downloads images from the web and display it in a GridView. My problem is that the GridView shows the images reduced in scale, the images haven 185px width, but the GridView shows them much smaller. For that reason there is a great gap horizontally between the images, and i want the images next to each other in 2 columns.

GridView adapter code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;

        }

        String url;
        Response.Movie temp=movieList.get(position);
        url=POSTER_BASE_URL+temp.getPoster_path();
        Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
       // imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);*/
        return imageView;
    }
```

and GridView in xml:

```
 <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
       />
```

Here a screen on how the GridView shows the images:
http://subefotos.com/ver/?24d92113e4c0f2c67c6b0276072b822ao.png

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Increment the value 185..may help you...

Comment: than you Kat-hat, i had to increment it by 900!!. Before i had incremented only by 300 and the looked same aspect.Stupid of me not haven realized before. But still have one problem more, in landscape mode exists a gap between the images. How can i get the images next to each other?

Comment: try adding android:adjustViewBounds="true" to GridView in xml

Comment: didn't worked this time http://subefotos.com/ver/?c053fed3cbc7f6e5c796e359f1e1bae2o.png#codigos

Comment: i have created a new resource directory called layout-land and put there mi xml with android:numColumns=3. Again, thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dp instead of px. It works based on the density and resolution.

```
new GridView.LayoutParams(dpToPx(185), dpToPx(185));

public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
    return px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you also, your solution works great also.I needed to put 270.